# Strangeness in reading a binary file in C

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, binaryfiles, file-pointer

I've defined a binary file like this in C

```
FILE *gfp;
gfp = fopen(gridfiles, "wb");
```

The variable gridfiles stores the name of the file, and has been defined earlier. Now I write out two variables into the file.

```
for(yy = 0; yy < nfiley; yy++) {
   for(xx = 0; xx < nfilex; xx++) {
      filebx = beguv + xx*1E3;
      fileby = enduv - yy*1E3;
      fwrite(&filebx, sizeof(filebx), 1, gfp);
      fwrite(&fileby, sizeof(fileby), 1, gfp);
   }
}
```

If *right after* this code I

```
fseek(gfp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(&filebx, sizeof(filebx), 1, gfp);
fread(&fileby, sizeof(fileby), 1, gfp);
fprintf(stderr, "%f %f", filebx, fileby);
```

my output is

```
1000 15000
```

for the first two, which is as expected.

But if after some assorted other code (that doesn't involve these files at all) I repeat the fseek() etc., my output is

```
14000 14000
```

regardless of what I do.
I've been trying to figure this out for a while now... anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you call  `fflush` appropriately?

Comment: I just added it and ran it again... same result! fflush() doesn't apply to fread by any chance, does it?

Comment: You know that it's UB to read from a file opened in write mode, right ? You should make it `fopen(gridfiles, "wb+");` if you plan to both read and write.

Comment: @PaulR - Too bad I only get one upvote. You're brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: No problem - I'll make it an answer if that has fixed things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to read from a stream which has been opened in write mode. You should make it:

```
gfp = fopen(gridfiles, "wb+");
```

if you plan to both read and write.

Also, as pointed out by @Kyle Jones in the comments above, you should get into the habit of checking the return status of `fread`/`fwrite` when doing file I/O - this would have caught your problem a lot earlier.